# regular expression and substitution with notepad++

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

1. At first I need a regex for a character **befor** 4 nummbers and substitute the chararter with another.

Example: **E**5015 -> **AI**5015 and  **E**5090 -> **AI**5090

```
Test String
2571130,733 5533151,436 E5015   6   16  E5015   16      
2576626,674 5531614,498 E5090   6   16  E50900  16      
2576614,102 5531577,319 E50/17  1   16  E50/17  16      
2567054,088 5538296,751 E5018   6   16  ;E5018  16  
2576606,227 5531589,142 E5070   6   16  Ei5070  16      
2584724,341 5502054,434 R7070   6   17  F7070   16  
2584735,918 5502107,131 R7014   6   17  R7014   16
```

regex: `[E]\d\d\d`

That is a character **with** 4 nummber and will not works because in the substitution you can't remember the value of the 4 nummbers

https://regex101.com/ is a usefull tool to test the regex

2. And then I wan't to use the Notepad function replace.

[image]

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/mgBVVw/2) help?

Comment: Can you show your desired end result based on the sample you have shown?

Comment: What about `;E5018` ? Try using a positive lookahead `\bE(?=\d\d\d\d\b)` and replace with `AI` https://regex101.com/r/Z9uZmy/1

Comment: Thanks everyone, hard to believe that there are so many different solutions, but they do their job. :-)  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `lookahead` operator to search for the digits without matching them:

```
(E)(?=\d{4})
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Jc4POI/1)

Here is the result in Notepad++
[image: Here is the result in Notepad++]